# Está aceptado vs. Es aceptado

Tags: cópulas

Can I use both *estar* and *ser* with the adjective *aceptado/a*?  ie.

> El niño **está aceptado** en la universidad

or is it

> El niño **es aceptado** en la universidad

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ha sido aceptado/admitido", or "fue aceptado/admitido", works and "está aceptado/admitido" does not to refer to a candidate having been admitted to university.

"estar aceptado" could be used to refer to some practice, or even some word, that has been or is accepted.

- No está aceptado (= Está prohibido) fumar en el aula. (Smoking in the classroom is not allowed / is forbidden.)
- La palabra "estándar" está aceptada. (The term "estándar" is an accepted word.)

"ser aceptado" in a simple tense could be used to refer to somebody being accepted by their peers.

- El mono no es aceptado por los gorilas. (The monkey is not accepted by the gorillas.)

Answer (score 7):

Both the following forms are common to refer to the *status* of havig been admitted:

> El niño *ha sido aceptado/admitido* en la universidad
>
> El niño *está aceptado/admitido* en la universidad

which means "the kid *has been admitted* to university". The first one sounds more correct to me, but [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22estoy%20admitido%22) [shows](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20sido%20admitido%22) that both are used on university websites.

"Ser aceptado/admitido" (being admitted) is a one-time event, and that is why, in this case, we refer to it in the past (*ha sido admitido*). You can use *es admitido* if you refer to the *event* of being admitted instead of the *status* of having been admitted, for example in a conditional sentence:

> Si el niño *es admitido* en la Universidad de Navarra, lo celebraremos (If the kid is admitted to the University of Navarra, we will celebrate it)

Note also that using the word *niño (kid)* to refer to someone at university age is very location-dependent: in some places (such as the north of Spain), you would say *mi hijo (my son)* or use his name instead.